# Pandas concat with outer join - Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, concatenation

I have 6 dataframes that contain information about unique customers like one df for emails the second one for first name .. etc

I am doing concat with outer join to have one df with all customer and information columns.

This is what I did so far:

```
info_dfs = (df1,df2,df3,df4,df5,df6)
```

Now the concatenation:

```
all_merged = pd.concat(
    objs=(dfs.set_index('ID') for dfs in info_dfs),
    axis=1,
    join='outer').reset_index().fillna(0)
```

But I get this error:

```
InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

I checked if individual dfs if they have duplicates but no one!
Then I checked each `df.index.is_unique` and all come `True`
I used `ignore_index=True` but the same error again!
Not sure what is the problem here

Comment: Can you reproduce the error in a minimum working example? I could not and the code you provide works fine. Consequently, the cause of the problem should be in your data, without which it will be difficult to troubleshoot it. Apart from that, try to update pandas.

Comment: I think you should update your Pandas version.

Comment: @harryhaller & Corralien Thanks guys :) .. updated pandas and it worked! I was so confused why it wasn't.

Answer (score 1):

IICU, `df1` ... `df6` share the `ID` column.
And may be some customers don't have complete all information, no email for example.

Try `pd.merge()`

Like this,

```
import pandas as pd
info_dfs = (df1,df2,df3,df4,df5,df6)
final_df=None
for i in info_dfs:
   if final_df is None:
      final_df=i
   else:
      final_df=pd.merge(final_df,i,on='ID')
final_df
```

hope this help.